# Import from excel to access

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I am having some troubles with a VBA code that should import excel data to my access database. When i run the code, i get a RunTime error "Runtime error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error".

```
With wks
    'arrêter l'importation lorsque l'on rencontre une case vide
    While .Range(A & i).Value <> ""
    '(où pKeyCol représente la colonne et i la ligne)

        If (cnt = 10) Then
'pour éviter les messages lors de l'ajout des enregistrements
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        End If

        'condition de remplissage de la table => eviter les doublons
        'si l'enregistrement existe déjà dans la table destination,
        'on passe à la ligne suivante sans l'importer
        If DCount("*", acTable, pKey & " LIKE '" & .Range(A & i).Value & "'") = 0 Then

            'requête SQL (ajouter autant de champs que nécessaire)
            cSQL = "INSERT INTO " & acTable & " ( [champ1], [champ2], [champ3], [champ5], [champ6], [champ11],[champ14], [champ15], [champ18],[champ20], [champ21], [champ22],[champ23], [champ24]) VALUES (" & Chr(34) & .Range("A" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("F" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("AI" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("X" & i) & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & .Range("H" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("K" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("R" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("S" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("AC" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("AD" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("AE" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("AF" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("AG" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("AH" & i) & Chr(34) & ");"
            'exemple avec les colonnes E et G

            'exécute la requète
            DoCmd.RunSQL cSQL

        End If

        'on incrémente la variable i pour passer à la ligne suivante
        i = i + 1
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Wend

End With
```

I think this is the section responsible. I think the problem might be because of champ  in the cSQL = part . I have coded this partly in a french environment . So this might be the problem.

Comment: When the error message appears and you click Debug what line does it take you to?

Comment: Does `acTable` contain spaces?

Comment: I am running this on access not excel. Also, when i use the compile in the debug panel, it doesn't find any error. When i run the button from access it returns the error. 
@Andy the table i give in the function call for acTable if "Table1" without spaces.

Comment: @user2497624 .. in VBA excel it should be .. `.Range("A" & text(i))`

Comment: @matzone There isn't a `text()` function in VBA.

Comment: @AndyG .. sorry, I mean `.Range("A" & format(i))` ...

Comment: No need to apologise, but there is no need for `format` either, just `.Range("A" & i)`. There is the `Str()` function but it is unnecessary in VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `A` is a variable then it should be:

```
.Range("A" & i)
```

which becomes `.Range("A1")` for example.

If `i` is initially 0 then this would create the error.

`acTable` is the name of a pre-existing Access enumeration so should not be used as a variable name (an identifier). It is a string so I would use `strTable` or `sTable`.

Comment: Thanks, Although i used the .RANGE("A" & i) in the cSQL = part i didn't use it in the loop. Thanks this solved my issue. However a new problem came up, "Erreur 3127 unknown field name 'CHAMP1' ..."  champ1 references the columns of the table i'm suupposed to import the data to. Do you happen to know how to reference it in english environment?

Comment: I don't know why that error occurs, or whether it is related to a language issue, unless the field-name doesn't occur in the table. Print out `cSql` and try to execute it from SQL View in Access.

Comment: I solved the issue. When i was trying to solve my issues; i modified the function that matches the string champ to the name of the column. thank u foryour help